How to create associated token account for a new mint?
I created a new token with metadata with this guide. Now I want to create the corresponding token account by using
        const tokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
            connection,
            payer,
            mint,
            payer.publicKey,
        );

However, I get a TokenAccountNotFoundError. I tried chatgpt, I tried using other methods to create a token account but I always got a different error. (Also tried saving the token address and then trying to create the token account a few minutes later)
TokenAccountNotFoundError
at unpackAccount (C:\Users\PycharmProjects\metadata\node_modules@solana\spl-token\src\state\account.ts:170:22)
at C:\Users\PycharmProjects\metadata\node_modules@solana\spl-token\src\state\account.ts:103:12
at Generator.next ()
at fulfilled (C:\Users\PycharmProjects\metadata\node_modules@solana\spl-token\lib\cjs\state\account.js:5:58)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Looks like you are missing the token program id.
The guide is showing how to interact with the token extensions program. So if you want to find the associated token account you also need to pass in that program id.
Like so:
programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID


Such a simple fix and it worked, thanks a lot!
